# ExtJS 4.1.0 proxy returns update api instead of create

Tags: django, extjs, proxy, crud

I was working on a code which was about integrating ExtJS 4 and Django. The link is:
https://github.com/diegocmsantos/extjs4-tdc2011-django

It works fine on ExtJS 4.0.0. But when I upgrade to 4.1.0 it's proxy returns update api instead of create.
I have added the 'idProperty' parameter to the Model, but still gives me the same result.

Model class:

```
Ext.define('TDC2011.model.Contact', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty: 'id',
    fields : [
            { name : "id", type : "int", mapping : "@id" },
            { name : "name", type : "string"},
            { name : "phone", type : "string"},
            { name : "email", type : "string"}]
});
```

Store Class:

```
Ext.define('TDC2011.store.Contacts', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'TDC2011.model.Contact',
    autoLoad: true,
    pageSize: 35,
    autoLoad: {start: 0, limit: 35},

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            read : 'contact/view.action',
            create : 'contact/create.action/',
            update: 'contact/update.action/',
            destroy: 'contact/delete.action/'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data',
            successProperty: 'success'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            writeAllFields: true,
            encode: false,
            root: 'data'
        },
        listeners: {
            exception: function(proxy, response, operation){
                Ext.MessageBox.show({
                    title: 'REMOTE EXCEPTION',
                    msg: operation.getError(),
                    icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
                    buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Is there anyone who knows the main cause of problem?

Comment: When you call model.save(), it returns a proxy action based on the boolean 'phantom' property. A record is considered to be 'phantom' if it exists on the front end but not on the back end. So, when you create a model instance and the idProperty (in your case, 'id') is set, it's not recognized as phantom and the update function will be used.